# How to remove breadcrumbs in Django admin

Tags: python, django

How can I use nav-global for navigation and hide the breadcrumbs in the django admin app. I've found ways to do this but they seem hackish and problematic. I'm looking for a clean reliable solution.

**Naive Approach that doesn't work:**

customize admin/base_site.html

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'Django site admin' %}{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'Django administration' %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}Some links will go here...{% endblock %}
{% block breadcrumbs %}{% endblock %}
```

this doesn't work because the templates in django admin like change_list.html that extend base_site.html will define content for breadcrumbs which will override whatever I have set in base_site.html.

**solution 1: CSS**

Add the following css to admin using the extrastyle block. This works, but the breadcrumbs still get generated and appear in the HTML source. This feels hacky.

```
.breadcrumbs {
    display: none;
}
```

**Solution 2: override base.html**

Override base.html and remove the breadcrumbs block. Children will try to define it but it never exists so it never gets rendered. This also seems like a hack. It's also not a good idea to override base.html as each Django release can make many changes to base.html and the admin app could break between releases.

Answer (score 2):

Extend all templates that you want to render an empty breadcrumbs block. Your first attempt (you say doesn't work) will work, just extend the other templates as well. Like change_list.html:

```
{% extends "admin/change_list.html" %}
{% block breadcrumbs %}
{% endblock %}
```

change_form.html:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}
{% block breadcrumbs %}
{% endblock %}
```

The same for:

- 500.html
- app_index.html
- change_password.html
- delete_confirmation.html
- delete_selected_confirmation.html
- invalid_setup.html
- object_history.html

login.html and index.html have an empty breadcrumb block.

Downside is that the templates need to be applied per app. This means duplicated templates. If you want to do project wide with single templates you end up with other hacks: copying the complete original templates OR let the templates extend `/path/to/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/template_name.html`.

Comment: This doesn't work. Try it out. You will get a maximum recursion depth exceeded error. Because admin/change_list.html is trying to extend admin/change_list.html.

Comment: You also missed a bunch of templates. There are 11 in total that would have to be overridden. They are: 500.html
app_index.html
auth/user/change_password.html
change_form.html
change_list.html
delete_confirmation.html
delete_selected_confirmation.html
index.html
invalid_setup.html
login.html
object_history.html

Comment: Tried it with change_form. It works. The template was in an app folder. I guess you want the templates to live higher so they are project wide. I can imagine Django running circles, but this was possible before (2009): http://www.slideshare.net/lincolnloop/customizing-the-django-admin slide 36. What changed since then? Template loaders?

Comment: Exactly. It will work if you do it for each app. It will be a lot of repetition though since it isn't in one place on a project level.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS. You can also hide app_label which is 2nd child.

```
.breadcrumbs>ul li:nth-child(2),
#grp-breadcrumbs>ul li:nth-child(2) {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the recursion problem:

1. Install django-apptemplates

   ```
   pip install django-apptemplates
   ```
2. Add the template loader to your settings.py. If you are using Django >= 1.8, add it in the TEMPLATES setting ([more details in the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/)).
3. You can now override a template by adding `app_name:` in the extends tag:

   ```
   {% extends "admin:admin/change_form.html" %}
   {% block breadcrumbs %}
   {% endblock %}
   ```